# Magento CMS Page - include external PHP script

Tags: php, magento

I want to include external PHP script in Magento CMS Pages

e.g.

```
**http://myhost/magento/custom/script.php**

<?php echo "hello"; ?>
```

Result on Magento Page should be: "`hello`"

**What would be the simplest way to do this?**

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/3698/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way would probably be via the Layout Update XML section (on the design tab). You can either create a new block for your template php file, or use `Mage_Core_Block_Template`. Add this:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="my_template" template="pat/to/your/template" after="cms_page" />
</reference>
```

Answer (score 4):

OR
You can use curly braces syntax in order to include .phtml file where you can write your PHP code as:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="my-template" template="path/to/your/template.phtml"}}
```

Thanks